# Android: Get all BroadcastReceivers' classes

Tags: android

I have an app, AppMain, and several plugin apps (but for this example, just one: AppPlugin):

AppPlugin registers a BroadcastReceiver in it's manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.plugin">
    ...
    <receiver android:name=".Receiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.LISTEN"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</manifest>
```

From AppMain, I use queryBroadcastReceivers() to get a list of all the receivers like so:

```
Intent intent = new Intent( "com.example.LISTEN" );
List<ResolveInfo> list = game.getPackageManager().queryBroadcastReceivers( intent, 0 )
```

`list` now contains a ResolveInfo from AppPlugin and I can get some useful information from it. All is good so far.

But I now want to get the class of AppPlugin's receiver registered in the manifest (in this case it would be "com.example.plugin.Receiver"). But I can't find a way to get that info from ResolveInfo.

So, how would I get BroadcastReceiver's class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're looking for `ResolveInfo#activityInfo.name`. As an example, for the first item in your list:

```
String name = list.get(0).activityInfo.name;
```

Comment: Perfect! I looked through the feilds in https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ActivityInfo.html but couldn't find anything. Didn't think to look in the superclass...